# App crashed H10 error when trying to open full-stack app on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I deployed a full-stack app on Heroku and when trying to open the app I get this error message:

at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=travelpinapp22.herokuapp.com request_id=d8a74b3e-7301-4f8c-9cde-eca1362ef55b fwd="51.146.234.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I tried many solutions found here on stack overflow but none worked so far.
any new ideas?
this is the GitHub repo https://github.com/marcodallomo/travelpinappmern.git

Thanks in advance:-)

Comment: Have you followed the following link? https://dev.to/lawrence_eagles/causes-of-heroku-h10-app-crashed-error-and-how-to-solve-them-3jnl   I don't know anything about Heroku, but I noticed there isn't a space between ```web:``` and ```node```.  Does that make a difference?  (just a guess)

Comment: @ewong thanks, I did, but without any luck, still getting the same error...